# How to auto stretch QTableView columns and keep them being adjustable

Tags: python, qt, header, pyqt, qtableview

I really like a clean result of self-adjusting to the `QTableView`'s width of the columns using:

```
self.view.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

But unfortunately with this flag used the columns width doesn't stay adjustable any longer (the user is not able to resize the columns width).

I wonder if there is an alternative way to set the columns width to the width of the `QTableView` and yet keeping the columns width "user-adjustable"?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']
        self.totalColumn=10

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return self.totalColumn
    def setColumnCount(self, number):
        self.totalColumn=number
        self.reset()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()


class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        self.view=QTableView(self) 
        self.view.setModel(tableModel)
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        hideButton=QPushButton('Hide Column')
        hideButton.clicked.connect(self.hideColumn)

        unhideButton=QPushButton('Unhide Column')
        unhideButton.clicked.connect(self.unhideColumn)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)
        layout.addWidget(hideButton)
        layout.addWidget(unhideButton)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def hideColumn(self):
        self.view.model().setColumnCount(1)

    def unhideColumn(self):
        self.view.model().setColumnCount(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As told in [Qt Doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) the size can't be changed. So I guess you will have to do a trick. When resizing the window, it could set your column width to `QTableView width / number of columns` using an event. I'll try to come up with a little script.

Comment: It would be interesting to see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so here is a little trick I came up with. I modified the resize event of MyWindow to resize your QTableWidget.

```
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        self.tableModel=Model(self) #Set the model as part of your class to access it in the event handler               

        self.view=QTableView(self) 
        self.view.setModel(self.tableModel) #Modified here too
        self.view.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive) #Mode set to Interactive to allow resizing

    hideButton=QPushButton('Hide Column')
    hideButton.clicked.connect(self.hideColumn)

    unhideButton=QPushButton('Unhide Column')
    unhideButton.clicked.connect(self.unhideColumn)

    layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.view)
    layout.addWidget(hideButton)
    layout.addWidget(unhideButton)
    self.setLayout(layout)

    def hideColumn(self):
        self.view.model().setColumnCount(1)

    def unhideColumn(self):
        self.view.model().setColumnCount(10)

    #Added a reimplementation of the resize event
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        tableSize = self.view.width() #Retrieves your QTableView width
        sideHeaderWidth = self.view.verticalHeader().width() #Retrieves the left header width
        tableSize -= sideHeaderWidth #Perform a substraction to only keep all the columns width
        numberOfColumns = self.tableModel.columnCount() #Retrieves the number of columns

        for columnNum in range( self.tableModel.columnCount()): #For each column
            self.view.setColumnWidth(columnNum, int(tableSize/numberOfColumns) ) #Set the width = tableSize / nbColumns
        super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event) #Restores the original behaviour of the resize event
```

The only downfall is that the scrollbar is flicking. I think this can be solved with some adjustment.

**Update:**
Get a cleaner look when resizing, no more flicking, disabled the scrollbar.

Modified initialization of the QTableView:

```
self.view=QTableView(self) 
self.view.setModel(self.tableModel)
self.view.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)
#Added these two lines
self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
self.view.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

Modified resizeEvent:

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
    tableSize = self.view.width()
    sideHeaderWidth = self.view.verticalHeader().width()
    tableSize -= sideHeaderWidth
    numberOfColumns = self.tableModel.columnCount()

    remainingWidth = tableSize % numberOfColumns 
    for columnNum in range( self.tableModel.columnCount()):
        if remainingWidth > 0:
            self.view.setColumnWidth(columnNum, int(tableSize/numberOfColumns) + 1 )
            remainingWidth -= 1
        else:
            self.view.setColumnWidth(columnNum, int(tableSize/numberOfColumns) )
```