# Why the width of the columns in the tableView does not change

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am writing the first model.

I can't change the width of the column headings, but the height changes!

The header width does not work.
The height of the header works.

[image]

**minimal reproducible example**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class QModelTable(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.data_list = data_list

    def columnCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.data_list[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        return len(self.data_list)

    def data(self, index, role=None):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()

        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.data_list[row][col]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=None):

        if role == QtCore.Qt.SizeHintRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                # I want a column width of 40px
                return QtCore.QSize(40, 40)  # The problem is here


test_data = (
    ('row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 3'),
    ('row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2', 'row 2 col 3'),
    ('row 3 col 1', 'row 3 col 2', 'row 3 col 3'),
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QModelTable(test_data)
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    table.setModel(model)

    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here’s what comes out of it:
[image]

Comment: I added an example

Comment: @АлександрРублев SizeHintRole is only used to calculate the sizeHint of each column, in this case 40, that is, the widget will try to establish that size 
**if it is possible**, that is, it is ideal but is subject to other elements such as: the size of the text, if established a fixed size, etc. For example if you reduce the width you will see that the minimum width is 40.

Comment: @eyllanesc Think that this is not so. If I want to set the column width to 200px, it won't work either.

Comment: @АлександрРублев As I told you, it takes it as a reference but it does not use it explicitly, QHeaderView depending on the [ResizeMode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#ResizeMode-enum) established uses a size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions for your problem. The most easy and effective way is to use a common item delegate for the column for which you want a "fixed" size and then set its resizeMode to `ResizeToContents`.

```
class FixedColumnDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, defaultWidth=None, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)
        self.defaultWidth = defaultWidth

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        hint = QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.sizeHint(self, option, index)
        if self.defaultWidth is not None:
            hint.setWidth(self.defaultWidth)
        return hint

    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = QModelTable(test_data)
    table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    table.setModel(model)
    table.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, FixedColumnDelegate(40, table))
    table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Just remember that, at least for PyQt, if you need more than an item delegate for an item view, you always need to set its parent or ensure that the delegate's instance is kept persistent as an object attribute (no matter what that object is, just ensure that it doesn't end up on the garbage collector at the end of the main class declaration or whenever you declare it), otherwise you'll face some unexpected and possibly hard to debug behavior: setting item delegates "on the fly" (as in instance declaration within the setItemDelegate*() function) will always create issues whenever you set more than one delegate in a view.

Answer (score 1):

To you give you a different spin if you look at this issue and its resolution perhaps you can get some incites about what to do that you might not have considered

[How to auto stretch QTableView columns and keep them being adjustable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185201/how-to-auto-stretch-qtableview-columns-and-keep-them-being-adjustable/28198138)